# Column not found in symfony mapped

Tags: php, symfony

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder

            ->add(child: 'Title')
            ->add('Image', FileType::class, [
                'mapped' => false
            ])

            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                   
                ]
            ]);
    }
```

As shown above i have stetted the value of mapped to false.But symfony is giving me an error column not found

Trying to add mapped false and i was expecting the field to not be linked to databases

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the exact error message. It might also be helpful to include the controller action method too.